# Boost.interprocess Vector as class member

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I would like to place a struct in a shared memory using Boost.Interprocess. This struct will be shared between two processes as a main exchange zone for serialized data. I am currently searching for the best solution in term of simplicity.

```
namespace bi = boost::interprocess;

typedef bi::allocator<SimpleData, bi::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>   ShmemSimpleDataAllocator;
typedef bi::vector<SimpleData, ShmemSimpleDataAllocator>                        SimpleDataVector;

struct SimpleData
{
    SimpleData() {}
    SimpleData(char* ptr)
        :data(ptr)
    {}

    /** Offset pointer to the data */
    bi::offset_ptr<char> data;
};

// Main shared structure
struct SharedMainStruct // EDITED, thanks Sehe
{
    SharedMainStruct(ShmemSimpleDataAllocator simple_allocator)
     :m_inputs(simple_allocator),
      m_outputs(simple_allocator)
    {}

    // Inputs, outputs and properties
    SimpleDataVector    m_inputs;
    SimpleDataVector    m_outputs;

    bi::interprocess_mutex     m_mutex;
    bi::interprocess_condition m_cond;
};

// Main code here
// Create managed shared memory
my_sho= new bi::managed_shared_memory (bi::create_only, "test_SO", 1000000);

// Build main structure in shared memory
ShmemSimpleDataAllocator data_allocator(my_sho->get_segment_manager());
m_main_struct = my_sho->construct<SharedMainStruct>("main")(data_allocator); // (1)
```

The idea is to place this `SharedMainStruct` in shared memory so that it is accessible for both processes. Is this code line (1) correct ? I would guess that I miss some runtime code like in the documentation right ? Like :

```
//Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
const ShmemSimpleDataAllocatoralloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());

//Construct a vector named "MyVector" in shared memory with argument alloc_inst
SimpleDataVector* myvector = segment.construct<SimpleDataVector>("SimpleDataVector")(alloc_inst);
```

-- UPDATE --

Yes, Vectors can be stored as member variables. We should provide allocators as parameters of the constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The essence:

Classes are laid out contiguously in memory, so you cannot *literally* store some parts of it selectively in shared memory.

For the same reason, storing `offset_ptr` outside shared-memory is useless, and you can simply replace it by a raw pointer.

### Further brainstorming

The previous two sentences should be enough to clear up any confusion.

You /can/ of course store the `MainStruct` in shared memory. This could help iff all data in the `MainStruct` can be shared.

If you need so share just that part of `MainStruct`, it seems obvious to make that explicit:

```
// Inputs, outputs and properties
struct SharedBuffers {
     template <typename Alloc> 
     SharedBuffers(Alloc alloc = {}) : m_inputs(alloc), m_outputs(alloc) {}

     Shared::Vector<SimpleData> m_inputs;
     Shared::Vector<SimpleData> m_outputs;
};

SharedBuffers* m_buffers; // bip::offset_ptr<> is overkill outside shared memory
```

Mild suggestion to replace the 'raw' offset_ptr` with a shared vector of char instead.

Comment: Yes I would like to put all the `MainStruct` in shared memory. I specified in my code : `m_main_struct = m_sho->construct<MainStruct>("main")();`.

Comment: Then why are you concerned about the vectors? Just make sure they use shared memory allocators, and be happy.

Comment: Well, I think I'm not too far from being happy. I just try to find the best solution to my problem. I rewrote partially my question. From your code, I have the impression that I can build my vector members through the initialization list by providing the allocator as an argument. Is that correct ?

Comment: You were right. I tried this
```ShmemSimpleDataAllocator data_allocator(m_sho->get_segment_manager());
 m_main_struct = m_sho->construct<MainStruct>("main")(data_allocator);``` and it seems to work well. Thanks a lot, that part of the documentation was not clear to me.

Comment: Indeed. I have quite a lot of answers on Boost Inteprocess, including scoped_allocator_adaptor that may make your life easier. Feel free to browse through them

Comment: Yes, I did find them before posting, but now it is clearer to me. Thanks again Sehe. :)